# Can we create a Application Domain inside another Application domain?

Tags: .net, clr

Inside an application Domain "AD1", try to crate another Application domain "AD2" (Like nested application domain). Is this possible?
e.g. When we create an process, that process will run in default application domain. In this process, if we create an new Application domain named "AD1", is this "AD1" is created inside default application domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*All* code runs within an application domain. There's no hierarchy or nesting - any AppDomain with sufficient permission can create one, but they're separate from each other.

Answer (score 2):

AppDomains are not nested. Every domain is a separate, isolated sandbox.

[Application Domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719528%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)